# Count how many checkboxes are checked with angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

Here is my checkboxes which i generate with ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let check of feature.tests; let i = index" class="col-md-12">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="i <= map[l][k]" [(ngModel)]="check.checked"
                  (change)="checkAll($event.checked, i ,k,  l)"
                  (ngModelChange)="changed(i)">{{check.name}} - {{feature.type}}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

when i click a checkbox, all the checkboxes with inferior index are checked as well and the checkboxes with superior index are unchecked

when i click here [check1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Y6V.png)
it do that [check2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXPgN.png)

so my counter should be at 2 with only 1 click

here the function that i use for check the checkboxes with previous indexes

```
checkAll(c, i: number, k, l) {
  if (c) {
    this.map[l][k] = i;
  } else {
    this.map[l][k] = i - 1;
  }
}
```

i would like to count how many checkboxes are checked and display the result in my HTML template, how could i achieve this ?

Comment: can you please post the `*ngFor` as well?

Comment: Yes i edited my post.

Comment: In your checkALL function can you try c.target.checked if true then maintain the record of the count in a variable for all checked values you will get the count.

Comment: `feature.tests` seems to contain all the checkboxes, right? so, you may apply a filter like this: `feature.tests.filter(i => i.checked).length;`. This will filter all the checked checkboxes and count them. You may use a getter in your angular view to accomplish such.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I hope the following solution will help you

You can trigger the event whenever checked or unchecked the box like bellow

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck2" (change)="checkBox($event);">
```

And call in ts file like bellow and you can modify it as per your requirement.

```
checkBox(enent){
     this.counter++; // counter is the varible
     if(this.counter%2==1){
       this.checked= true; //checked is the variable
    }
    else{
      this.checked=false;
     }
  }
```

Comment: thanks but how do i count how many checkboxe are checked in total ?

Comment: There are two ways that I know

Comment: There are two ways that I know. One is you can call the same method in all checkboxes and increase counter there in that method. Another is call the different methods in each checkbox and increase the same counter in these methods.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put the checkboxes into a form anfd then subscribe to their valuechanges like this:

html is the same but wrap it around with a form tag like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
...
</form>
```

ts:

```
form: FormGroup;
count=0
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(()=>{
   for(let i=0; i<this.form.value.length; i++){
      if(this.form.value[i]==true){
       count++
      }
 }}
```

Comment: sorry you have to declare form as well
and the name have to match with the formgroup  value